# mostrar el ultimo dato db laravel

Tags: laravel

Hola Tengo este problema con laravel [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi codigo

```
$last = DB::table('nombre_votos')->select('id')
               ->orderby('created_at','DESC')->first();
 return view('user/votos/index',compact('last'));
```

la idea es que me muestre el ultimo **nombre** que se a creado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
se muestra asi [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Ramón bienvenido al Sitio, ¿Cómo imprime la variable $last en su vista ? además dice que desea mostrar el nombre pero solo está seleccionado el id .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba con el método `take()` al cual le indicas la cantidad de elementos a tomar asi: `take(1)` y al final usas el método `get()` *esto retornará una colección de un elemento *

```
  $data = DB::table('nombre_votos')
                 ->select('nombrePersona')
                 ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')
                 ->take(1)
                 ->get();

 return view('welcome')->with(["data" => $data]);//sustituye por tu                                               
 vista
```

Al usar el ordenamiento `DESC` y usar el método take(1) con el númnero uno, el query builder sabrá que solo va a tomar un solo elemento y que este sea el último registrado.

En el `select` quita la columna id y coloca el nombre de la columna que guarda los nombres como en mi ejemplo

**Resultado esperado**

Una vez que ejecutes tu consulta tu resultado debería ser muy similar a esto

```
[
  {
   "nameUser": "delta"
  }
]
```

> Solo debes ajustar los nombres de tus columnas

**Actualización**

Como se esta retornando una colección, en la vista puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
@foreach($data as $d)
   {{ $d->nameUser }}//sustituye nameUser por el nombre de la columna tuya
@endforeach
```

También puedes obtenerlo del modo siguiente

```
 $data = \DB::table('users')
                     ->select('nameUser', 'users.id')
                     ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->first();

     return view('welcome')->with(["data" => $data]);
```

Como `first` me devuelve un solo elemento ahora en la vista puedo leerlo el valor así

```
{{ $data->nameUser }}
```

Comment: hola si sirvirvio pero como hago para mostrar solo el nombre  utilize el json_encode($last) pero sale asi [{"nombre":"KGJG"}] como hago para que solo se vea el KGJG solo ?

Comment: mostrar el nombre donde? en tu vista? @RamonAlbares

Comment: @RamonAlbares mira mi respuesta actualizada

Comment: si ya me funciono Gracias!!!

Comment: Si desea obtener "el último dato" no creo que sea necesario un `foreach`, podría añadir a su respuesta el método `latest()` junto con `first()` y obtener solo 1 elemento.

Comment: buena observación @Dev.Joel lo agrego

Comment: utilizando el latest? un ejemplo para no utilizar el foreach

Comment: En el último ejemplo que puse ya no es necesario el foreach, al estar ordenando de manera descendente va a leer del ultimo registro hasta el primer registro y al usar el método first, la indicamos que se detenga en el ultim registro hecho

Comment: gracias!! ya lo pude hacer :3

Comment: @RamonAlbares en lugar de realizar el `orderBy` , existe `latest()` que internamente realiza este proceso. es decir `DB::table('nombre_votos')->select('id','name')->latest()->first();`